# Flutter how can i change color of container on tap?

Tags: flutter

I am using for loop to show the next 5 days and month. I need to change the color example text color or border color when the user clicks on that box and just prints the date and month whom the user clicks on.

This is my code

```
 class _BookService3State extends State<BookService3> {
  final _currentDate = DateTime.now();
  final _dayFormatter = DateFormat('d');
  final _monthFormatter = DateFormat('MMM');
  final _dayyFormatter = DateFormat('EEE');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dates = <Widget>[];
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double Height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double Width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      final date = _currentDate.add(Duration(days: i));
      dates.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          height: Height * 0.13,
          width: Width * 0.2,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  _monthFormatter.format(date),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: Height * 0.002,
                ),
                Text(_dayFormatter.format(date),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 25)),
                SizedBox(
                  height: Height * 0.002,
                ),
                Text(_dayyFormatter.format(date),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                        fontSize: 18)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: dates.map((widget) => widget).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I need is this

[image]

Mean user can click one box and the box color change and print that box date.

Comment: Look up AnimatedContainer and see if its what your looking for. https://youtu.be/yI-8QHpGIP4

Comment: you can implement it, or you could use toggle buttons widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with InkWell widget. First, you need to define a currentindex variable. After that, onTap method of the InkWell widget, set that index to currentindex variable. Then you can check the current index while defining your Color.

It will look like this:

```
class _BookService3State extends State<BookService3> {
  final _currentDate = DateTime.now();
  final _dayFormatter = DateFormat('d');
  final _monthFormatter = DateFormat('MMM');
  final _dayyFormatter = DateFormat('EEE');

// Define our current index!
  int currentindex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dates = <Widget>[];
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      final date = _currentDate.add(Duration(days: i));
      dates.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              // set current index!
              currentindex = i;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: height * 0.13,
            width: width * 0.2,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: currentindex == i ? Colors.white : Colors.blue, // Here we checked!
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    _monthFormatter.format(date),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                        fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.002,
                  ),
                  Text(_dayFormatter.format(date),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 25)),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.002,
                  ),
                  Text(_dayyFormatter.format(date),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                          fontSize: 18)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: dates.map((widget) => widget).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but issue is how can i set the index . your question is right but i need to set the blue color only on which box user tap or click

Comment: Here we are setting current index in the onTap of the InkWell widget.

Comment: but its not changing i think its fixed. MEan as you define current index 1 its showing white box on that box which index is 1 which is correct but on tap its not changing the current index